# Forgotten "new" declaration in collection initialization: what does this code do, and why does it compile?

Tags: c#, collections

When initializing objects, I often write code like this:

```
var myObj = new MyObject
{
    Number = 1,
    ListOfStuff = new List<Stuff>
    {
        new Stuff()
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I forget the `new List<Stuff>`, and instead write:

```
var myObj = new MyObject
{
    Number = 1,
    ListOfStuff =
    {
        new Stuff()
    }
}
```

I wouldn't expect this to compile, but it does. `ListOfStuff` isn't initialized as I would expect, however -- it's empty. What exactly does this code actually do?

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.5 or 4.6 ?

Comment: .NET 4.0, C# language 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both object initialization syntax and collection initialization syntax are just syntactic sugar transformed by compiler at compile time insto assignments and method calls:

- object initialization syntax is transformed into property assignments,
- collection initialization syntax is transformed into proper `Add` method calls

So your code is equivalent to:

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.Number = 1;
myObj.ListOfStuff.Add(new Stuff());
```

It's a valid C# code and it will work if default constructor on `MyObject` initializes `ListOfStuff` property. It will throw `NullReferenceException` if it doesn't.

The first version of your code explicitly assigns `new List()` to `ListOfStuff` before calling `Add`:

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.Number = 1;
myObj.ListOfStuff = new List<Stuff>();
myObj.ListOfStuff.Add(new Stuff());
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the explanation. You're right that my default constructor for `MyObject` initializes `ListOfStuff`. However, in my (real) code it creates the `new Stuff()` object, but doesn't add it to the list (according to the debugger). It's as if the part of the block which should be turned into `Add(new Stuff())` is just swallowed and ignored. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting also that the following way of initializing ListOfStuff will generate a compile error:

```
    var myObj = new MyObject();
    myObj.Number = 1;
    myObj.ListOfStuff = 
        {
            new Stuff()
        };
    };
```

Comment: This may be interesting, but how does it answer the question that was asked?